# Calculating total price of items added

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question. I'm trying to make a feature similar to shopping cart where user adds item to "cart" then if they adjust the quantity of the item, the total price changes based on quantity.

Currently, I have two inputs, retail price and quantity. If either the retail price or quantity changes, then I have to update the total amount.

Oddly, if I update the quantity of item, product*quantity is reflected correctly in the application. However, if I only update the retail price, then nothing is updated until I once again update the quantity.

What am I doing wrong here?

html snippet:

```
<span>
    <div>Retail Price* </div>
    <div><input #retailPrice formControlName="retailPrice" value="{{product.price}}" (change)="updateTotal(retailPrice.value, quantity.value)" placeholder="{{'EnterPrice' | translate}}"/>x</div>
</span>
<span>
    <div>Qty</div>
    <div >
        <input #quantity type='number' name='quantity' value="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value=1);" class='qty' (change)="updateTotal(retailPrice.value, quantity.value)"/>=</div>
</span>
<span>
    <div>
        Price
    </div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div>
        ${{totalAmount | number : '1.2-2'}}
    </div>
</span>
```

updateAmount function:

```
 updateTotal(retailPrice: number, number: number) {
      this.quantity = number;
      this.totalAmount = retailPrice * number;
  }
```

Comment: Try to use `(keyup)` instead of `(change)` to update at keystoke moment.

Comment: @Abra001 I tried but same issue

Comment: It's because you are binding the value with `{{product.price}}`, try to remove this attribute.

Comment: @Abra001 I need the price to be bound to the input initially. That's the normal price of the item. It needs to be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `(change)` is not for text inputs. You should use `(keypress)` or `(keyup)`

Second, you forgot to close a `<div>` tag after `<input #quantity...>`

Third, your code seems to be properly working. Does your console logs any error?

Comment: Try to change the code as I said. Close the `<div>` tag and change your `change` event to `keyup` and see if the problem still occurs. Also, try to do this code with hardcoded values (remove the dynamic forms).

Comment: I did add the div tag (sorry it was only missing in the SO post because my copy and paste skills are terrible). I did change it to keyup but still same behavior. I'll try with hardcoded values.

Comment: I made it working by removing the formControlName because I didn't have your app logic. Maybe it's the broken part...

Comment: Glad to help. Regards

Answer (score -1):

this is because your total amount is only set after you update your total with your function, you should update the total after you change the detail price.

Comment: I also tried adding change event to retail price but after I type it in, I don't get an update in total price.

Comment: Try to bowdlerize yourself next time without counting on anyone to edit your posts.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me you where using reactive forms, i created a quick stackblitz, in which you can update the different values every time your form values change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1wmyl

Answer (score -1):

```
<span>
    <div>Retail Price* </div>
     <div><input #retailPrice formControlName="retailPrice" ng-model= 
         "product.price" placeholder="{{'EnterPrice' | translate}}"/>x</div>
</span>
<span>
      <div>Qty</div>
      <div >
           <input #quantity type='number' name='quantity' ng- 
                model='quantity' oninput="validity.valid||(value=1);" 
             class='qty' />
      </div>
</span>
<span>
      <div>Price</div>
       <div><br></div>
       <div>
             ${{produce.price * quantity | number : '1.2-2'}}
        </div>
</span>
```

Set a two way binding between the inputs and objects product.price and quantity in your controller's scope. Set a default value for quantity to 1.

Note: instead of surrounding divs with spans, set divs to inline in your css or styling attributes so that there is no line breaks.

Comment: I'm using reactive forms for Angular 5, so I can't use ng-model or ngModel. I'll look into how I can use two way data binding in reactive forms but maybe [value]=?

Comment: I noticed, do you need formControlName attribute for quantity as well? Not sure don't know anything about angular 5